# How to invert values in string?

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I must invert the values of string, changing one by other.

Example:

```
var x = "my string";
x = someCrazyFunction(x, 'm', 'n');
```

Then x that was "**m**y stri**n**g" will become "**n**y stri**m**g"

How to achieve this?

Comment: Please post what you have tried to solve the problem and what specific issue you ran into.

Comment: There's more than enough information here to answer the question without "what have you tried"

Comment: @Plynx, I am more than happy to help if the OP tried to do something and ran into problems, but I don't come here to do other people's thinking for them.

Comment: @gpojd I wasn't talking to you. At least one comment that has since been deleted was extremely unwelcoming. I don't like it when veterans pile on a newcomer's first question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function someCrazyFunction(str, ch1, ch2) {
    return str.replace(/./g, function(x) {
        return (x == ch1) ? ch2 : (x == ch2) ? ch1 : x;
    });
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bqtYN/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
x.split('').map(function(c) {return c=='n'?'m':c=='m'?'n':c; }).join('');
```

Or if you want to use an object for your remapping (for any quantity of craziness):

```
x.split('').map(function(c) {var _={n:'m',m:'n'}; return c in _?_[c] : c;}).join('')
```